# React Native- useContext 'is not a function' error while trying to update a survey from user input

Tags: react-native, use-context

Hi I am trying to add a  Usecontext in order to share the same data between different component for a survey with React Native.

I am getting an error message : 'submitForm() TypeError: setEvent is not a function'

Here is the QuestionsProvider Component

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { QuestionsContext } from '@/shared/contexts';


 export const QuestionsProvider = ({children}) => {

const [event, setEvent] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
console.log('the event changed --->', event)
  }, [event]);

return (
 <QuestionsContext.Provider value={{...QuestionsContext, event, setEvent}}>
    {children} 
  </QuestionsContext.Provider>
);
};
```

And here is the Whathappened component where I am using Formik for the input :

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import t from '@/locales';
import styles from '../TrainingGoingScreen.styles';

import ButtonStart from '@/shared/component/ButtonStart';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';


import { QuestionsProvider } from '@/shared/contexts/providers/QuestionsProvider';
import { QuestionsContext } from '@/shared/contexts';


export default function Whathappened(props) {

    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    const {event, setEvent} = useContext(QuestionsContext);

  // ca ne fonctionne pas not function  const {event, setEvent} = useContext(QuestionsContext);
 
    useEffect(() => {
      if (redirect === true) {
        props.navigation.navigate('Whatdidyouthink');
      }
    }, [redirect]);

    const nextPage = async (values) => {
      setEvent(values)
      console.log('event ---> ', event)

      };

  return (
    <QuestionsProvider>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={{minHeight:'100%'}}>
      <Formik
        onSubmit={(values) => nextPage(values)}
        initialValues={{
          happened: '',
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
          happened: yup.string().required(),
        })}>
        {({
          values,
          handleChange,
          errors,
          setFieldTouched,
          touched,
          handleSubmit,
        }) => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.centeredtitle}>
                {t('training.goingon.whathappened')}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.description}>
                {t('training.goingon.question')}
                {' 1 '}
                {t('training.goingon.ofnumber')}
              </Text>
              {/* User input */}
              <TextInput
                placeholder={t('training.goingon.inputanswer')}
                value={values.happened}
                placeholderTextColor="grey"
                onChangeText={handleChange('happened')}
                onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('happened')}
                style={styles.input}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="default"
                textContentType="name"
                returnKeyType="next"
              />
              {touched.happened && errors.happened && (
                <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
                  {t('training.goingon.inputanswer')}
                </Text>
              )}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottom}>
              <ButtonStart
                onPress={handleSubmit}
                buttonText={t('training.goingon.nexquestionbutton')}
                showRightArrow={true}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>


    </QuestionsProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the app reducer to solve this:

```
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_BEHAVIOUR':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            behaviour: action.behaviour,
          };
}
```